# How to modify array with checkbox selection (It's ready just need to modify something)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'll try to be short and get to the point.

When I choose a role, it adds it to an array with the role's name and whether it's selected or not (with true or false). Actually the array is saved the following way:

```
[
  {
    "name": "CDB_DBA",
    "selected": true
  },
  {
    "name": "CONNECT",
    "selected": true
  }
]
```

and I need it to be saved this way (with the roles I select from the checkbox list):

```
["CDB_DBA", "CONNECT"]
```

The array contains the selected roles, I'm sure it's pretty simple to change but I'm new to this and need some help. Thank you in advance. Here's the JSBin link to the project:

[JSBin Project](http://jsbin.com/fukakuqega/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your link by creating a new array and pushing the value into that array while checking the checkbox

Can you check this is expected? If not please explain it briefly.

**please check the below link**

http://jsbin.com/huwepirolo/edit?html,js,output

```
 $scope.updateArray= function(value){
      alert(value);
      $scope.array.push(value);
    }
```

Comment: I've found a little bug, when I deselect one role It still adds it to the array everytime I click on the checkbox, any way to fix it? thanks in advance.

Comment: Heyy yaa i have fixed it. please check the below link I have updated the code    http://jsbin.com/ropeqeqicu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Ajay, I've got one last request,when I click on the edit button it brings the selected user roles, is there any way to save them in the $scope.array = [];.... It checks the checkbox roles the user has but does not update the roles inside $scope.array, I hope you understood me, thank you very much you're a life savior, I've updated screenshots to imgur to illustrate you in a better way... [link](http://imgur.com/a/ErwFS) @ajaykumar

Comment: Heyy @Aceman I have updated the code, Can you check is this expected or I misunderstood.  http://jsbin.com/ropeqeqicu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: updated small mistake http://jsbin.com/zeyivaqogi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: It is working smoothly, is there any way you can clear the array when I click on other user's edit button, when I do it it does not empty the previous user's roles in the array, thank you very much, I owe you my life.

Comment: hehe.. It's okay bro :) I have updated the code http://jsbin.com/heburetehi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you very much Ajay, I'm sorry for asking a lot of things but I'm new to Angular and to be honest I had not received any guidance until you helped me, greetings from Colombia and I hope to meet you in real life.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert an array in the upper format to the lower one, you could use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out just `selected` elements and then [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to pick out the `name` attribute:

```js
var input = [
  {
    "name": "foo",
    "selected": false
  },
  {
    "name": "bar",
    "selected": true
  },
  {
    "name": "memes",
    "selected": false
  },
  {
    "name": "quux",
    "selected": true
  },
  {
    "name": "xyzzy",
    "selected": false
  },
  {
    "name": "corn",
    "selected": true
  }
];

var output = input
               .filter(obj => obj.selected) // filter out non-selected elements
               .map(obj => obj.name);       // just get the name
console.log(output);
```

Note that this leaves `input` unmodified; `output` is a new array.